# Changing textview text from another view

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-view

I have a class lets call it "A", that extends from View, which draws something. I also have below it a relative layout with a text view. I would like to edit the text of the text view from one of the methods of "A". I tried to use findViewById function, however it returns null on the textview.. Is it possible to do that? Or my design is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `findViewById` before `setContentView` is done?
If so, it may return null.
Try to use `findViewById` after `setContentView`.

Comment: Yes I do call setContentWindow before. This is an example of my code: https://pastebin.com/4RT8V0Qa, I try to change the textvew in the startTraining method.